# How do I point my w2k3 application server to use the database on my MsSQL2005 server

Tags: sql-server

How do I point my application server to use the database on my MsSQL2005 server. Both are on the same domain running w2k3.

Thank you

Maxman

Comment: What application are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the connection string and change the server name from localhost to the servername.

You can check http://www.connectionstrings.com.